# How to stream a video from one pc to another in internet using UDP VLC

Tags: udp, streaming, vlc

I just wanted to know how can i stream a video using `UDP` in `VLC` media player from one system to another system through internet.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to stream video using VLC in http to other computer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65293175/how-to-stream-video-using-vlc-in-http-to-other-computer)

Comment: @RaymondChen actually that was related to ```http``` protocol and this one is related to ```UDP``` because I want to do the streaming using both of them that's why I asked them as different questions.

Comment: What programming language are you using? The way the two questions are phrased, it sounds like you are just using the vlc program, not writing your own program.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am using ```c++``` for writing these codes or more specifically I am using ```libvlc VLC Qt wrapper``` in ```QT c++``` to accomplish this tasks but the code for the streaming is nothing but just need to pass the ```stream output string``` in the ```VlcMedia*``` object and this ```stream string output``` i am taking from the ```Vlc``` application. So I am just trying to solve this problem using ```Vlc``` application because converting this thing to code is not that much hard.

Comment: You should include that context in the question, and perhaps include some code that you've written so far so people know where your starting point is.